# Symfony Custom field type for serialized field Doctrine type

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to create a custom field type that would transform 2 (or more) text input types into a serialized array into my entity "meta_data" field. So far i have:

Entity:

```
// @ORM\Column(type="object")
private $meta_data;
->setMetaData($data) { $this->meta_data = serialize($data); }
->getMetaData($data) { $this->meta_data = unserialize($data); }
```

I have created my custom field type and added in the buildForm method :

```
// class SerializedFieldType buildForm method
$builder
    ->add('tagline')
    ->add('description')
```

The field types extends the text type. In my form builder interface i can successfully use that custom field type which now show two fields in place of the meta data form field :

```
// main form type buildForm method
->add('meta_data', new FieldType\SerializedFieldType()
```

Now i'm trying to figure out how i can use data transformer(s) to both set the unserialized entity data into each of its own field, and transform it back again to serialized data when the form is posted.

I have read Sf custom field type docs and DataTransformers section.

Any help will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: You could use Doctrine's built-in types such as `json_array`, `simple_array`, `array`...

Comment: Yes, that is already the case, but how to re-united several fields so that all the fields data get serialized in that field ?